# Finding the characteristic function of a 2nd order ODE with variables on both sides

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, characteristic-functions

The given function is
$$x^2y^{''}+xy^{"}+y=\ln(x)$$
Now finding the characteristic or aux. function is very simple, usually. This problem has $x$ terms on both sides of the equation. 
Would it be better to move all the $x$ terms to the right hand side, thus making the equation:
$$y^{"}+y^{'}+y=\frac{\ln(x)}{x^3}$$
Or should it be done after the change of the $y$ terms, the reasoning being that the equation Aux. now will have a variable within the $m$ term:
$$m^2x^2+mx+1=0$$
$$(m+1)(x^2m+x)=0$$
$$m_1=-1 \space m_2=-\frac{1}{x}$$
But I do see this being a far more complex way to solve, if not flat out wrong. Should I try to remove the $x$ terms before the change to $m$'s occurs or should I solve $m$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: You can do that ..Move all the x that way. This DE is EulerCauchy 's differential equation...

Comment: You have two terms with $y''$ check your equation Eric.

Comment: Here are many points wrong! First, that isn’t a function, that is a differential equation! Second, the second displayed equation is definitely wrong. Third, what you have done in equation 3, 4 and 5 is totally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2y''+xy'+y=\ln(x)$$
Substitute $x=e^t$ the equation becomes:
$$y''+y=t$$
Which is easier to integrate.